# Python: how to print "word" without white space after and before ""

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have the following print statement in python:

```
print '"' This '"' is xyz'
```

It prints as follows: `" word " is xyz`
In other words, it has a white space before first `"` and a white space each before and after the word `'This'`.

My question: how can I change the print statement so that the white space before the first `"` and white spaces before and after the word `'This'` is  not printed?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Java has swing, and one swings when he plays cricket, so that has several puns.

Comment: The line of code you posted doesn't make sense, since the quotes are not balanced. What is the actual line of code?

Answer (score 3):

If you meant to print the literal word "This", surrounded by quotes, try this:

```
print '"This" is xyz'
```

If you meant to print the variable `This`, which is bound to the string `word`, try this:

```
This = 'word'
print '"{}" is xyz'.format(This)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? You can use `\"` for a `"` in a string constant.

```
>>> print "\"This\" is xyz"
"This" is xyz
>>>
```

Comment: You don't even need the backslashes if you use a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

```
print '"This" is xyz'
print '"This" is xyz'
```